# Como ordenar todos resultados de una consulta que tengan el mismo ID de usuario?

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Tengo una script que consulta en menús desplegables los pedidos de los usuarios la consulta es así:

```
<?php

  $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT Ord.ID, Ord.Tipo_Pago, Ord.Cambio, Ord.Qty, Ord.Estatus, Pro.Nombre_Producto, Pre.Precio*Ord.Qty, Du.Nombre, Dir.Direccion, Dir.Colonia, Dir.CP 
    FROM Orden AS Ord 
    INNER JOIN Productos AS Pro ON Ord.ProductoID = Pro.ID
    INNER JOIN Lista_Precios AS Pre ON Ord.ProductoID = Pre.ProductoID
    INNER JOIN Datos_Usuarios AS Du ON Ord.UsuarioID = Du.ID
    INNER JOIN Domicilios_Entrega AS Dir ON Ord.UsuarioID = Dir.UsuarioID WHERE Ord.Estatus != "Entregado" AND Ord.Estatus != "Cancelado"');

    $statement->execute();

    while($datos_pedidos = $statement->fetch() ) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="box box-default collapsed-box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo $datos_pedidos["Nombre"]; ?></h3><br>
              <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo $datos_pedidos["Colonia"]; ?></h3>
              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <!-- /.box-tools -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <p>Producto: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Nombre_Producto"]; ?></p>
              <p>Total: $ <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Pre.Precio*Ord.Qty"]; ?></p>
              <p>Cantidad: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Qty"]; ?></p>
              <p>Pago: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Tipo_Pago"]; ?></p>
              <p>Cambio: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Cambio"]; ?></p>
              <p>Usuario: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Nombre"]; ?></p>
              <p>Direccion: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Direccion"]; ?></p>
              <p>Colonia: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Colonia"]; ?></p>
              <p>CP: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["CP"]; ?></p>
              <p>Estado: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Estatus"]; ?></p>
              <p><a href="funcion_modificar_pedido.php?ID=<?php echo $datos_pedidos['ID'] ?>" class="btn bg-orange margin"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <?php } ?>
```

La cuestión es que trae producto por producto y yo quiero que traiga los pedidos de un usuario en una sola ventana actualmente se ve así:
[image: Varias Pestañas para un solo usuario]

Como se ve en la imagen hay cinco ventanas para un solo usuario y debería ser una con todos los productos que ordeno, he intentado con ORDER BY, GROUP BY pero sin éxito......

Comment: Te recomiendo que hagas `sum(Ord.Qty)` y `sum(Pre.Precio*Ord.Qty)` y agrupes por los demás campos, obviamente sin incluir en el group by los que te menciono, solamente debes tener en cuenta que al hacer group by si un campo es diferente, te creara otra fila y por ende otro detalle de producto. Saludos.

Comment: @JosueArriola Exactamente lo que quiero es que no haga un GROUP BY de un solo registro sino que agrupe todos en un solo grupo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenés que hacer dos llamados dstintos: Uno llamando a los clientes y, dentro, poner el segundo *while* dentro de la clase *.box-body*. Te quedará uno dentro del otro. Algo así:

```
<?php while($datos_clientes = $statementClientes->fetch()){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="box box-default collapsed-box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo $datos_pedidos["Nombre"]; ?></h3><br>
          <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo $datos_pedidos["Colonia"]; ?></h3>
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-tools -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
        <?php while($datos_pedidos = $statementProductos->fetch() ) { ?>
                <p>Producto: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Nombre_Producto"]; ?></p>
                <p>Total: $ <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Pre.Precio*Ord.Qty"]; ?></p>
                <p>Cantidad: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Qty"]; ?></p>
                <p>Pago: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Tipo_Pago"]; ?></p>
                <p>Cambio: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Cambio"]; ?></p>
                <p>Usuario: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Nombre"]; ?></p>
                <p>Direccion: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Direccion"]; ?></p>
                <p>Colonia: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Colonia"]; ?></p>
                <p>CP: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["CP"]; ?></p>
                <p>Estado: <?php echo $datos_pedidos["Estatus"]; ?></p>
                <p><a href="funcion_modificar_pedido.php?ID=<?php echo $datos_pedidos['ID'] ?>" class="btn bg-orange margin"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></p>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: En la primera consulta ya traigo todos los datos, porque hacer otra? examinaste bien mi consulta?

Comment: Se puede hacer también con un ciclo for y con if (esta condición es para chequear que el usuario sea el mismo). Pero no todo dentro de un mismo while, así como está planteado arriba. Pero creo que es más sencillo llamar primero a los usuarios y luego un llamado completo. Dos consultas no es lo ideal pero es sencillo, cómodo y funciona.

Comment: el cliente lo quiere con WHILE no tengo opcion.....

Comment: Uhhhh, dos consultas, mira he tenido problemas usando dos consultas asi que lo descartare

Comment: Con while vas a recorrer TODO siempre y tenés que hacer un filtro en el id de usuario antes de dibujar el .box.

Comment: Podrias darme un ejemplo

Comment: Dos consultas no es complicado, al contrario. Eso sí, tal vez sea menos eficiente. Pero con pocos usuario no pasa nada. Primero consultás los usuarios y lo guardás en una variable. Luego, con la segunda consulta hecha, dibujas el .box solamente si tiene pedidos. AL hacer el wuile de todos los pedidos primero, te dibuja una caja por pedido, porque los recorre todos.

Comment: El problema es que se va a usar de de modo masivo es para muchos clientes necesito hacerlo en la misma consulta solo aplicando un filtro

Comment: Te muestro cómo lo hice yo: Comparo a los alumnos con el id del curso, si coinciden, pertenece a este curso e imprimo el listado. Así (yo usé foreach, pero con while es igual):                                                                                                                                                          foreach ($alumnos as $key => $value) {                            
      if($value['curso'] == $curso_actual['id']){ // Acá imprimo lo que deseo. }  }

Comment: Al listado de alumnos ya lo tengo desde el principio (y los dejo en la variable $alumnos), porque lo uso varias veces. Con los clientes te pasará lo mismo: los vas a necesitar muchas veces en la aplicación.

Comment: Lo estoy intentando como lo sugeriste y le pedi que me trajera los registros que pertenenecen a un ID de usuario esta correcto?

Comment: ¡Exactamente! Seguí probando así que lo vas a encontrar. Así estoy aprendiendo también yo: mirando cursos peros, sobre todo, tirando código. A esto último no se puede escapar. XD

Comment: Claro, bueno de cualquier forma marco como aceptada tu respuesta

Comment: Espero que lo resuelvas como te lo pidieron y que aprendas. Resolviendo problemas es una excelente manera de hacerlo.